# OpenCV CUDA_ARCH_BIN for GTX 1080Ti

Tags: opencv, object-detection, nvidia

I want to perform an object detection on a GeForce GTX 1080Ti.

I've downloaded and installed CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 successfully (followed this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/yolov4-with-cuda-powered-opencv-dnn-2fef48ea3984).
After that I've built opencv-4.5.1 from source, using CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 (as found here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute).

When I try to perform detection I recieve the following error:

```
File "./image_detector.py", line 308, in make_prediction
outputs = self.net.forward(self.layer_names)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /home/ubuntu/opencvbuild/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:2373: error: (-216:No CUDA support) OpenCV was not built to work with the selected device. Please check CUDA_ARCH_PTX or CUDA_ARCH_BIN in your build configuration. in function 'initCUDABackend'
```

I have tried to build OpenCV with 5.3 and 7.5 CUDA_ARCH_BIN versions but got the same error.

It is my first time working with Nvidia GPU's and I'm a bit confused by all the versions and compatibility between them.

Checking CUDA installation:

```
nvidia-smi 
Fri Apr  2 07:02:04 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   24C    P8     8W / 250W |      1MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Nvcc output:

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
```

And location:

```
which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin/nvcc
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad No :(

Answer (score 0):

I was following this link to install opencv and caffe2. I was faced with the same problem of opencv not being built with cudnn.

https://techboutique-official.medium.com/how-to-setup-caffe-with-cuda-10-1-and-cudnn-7-6-5-in-ubuntu-20-04-complete-guide-7a7f58cf0616

After hours of looking for a working solution, I came across this website
https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/
that motivated me to come up with a combination of cmake flags (correct me if I'm technically wrong) which helped me successfully go through the cmake process with CUDA and cudnn.

I specifically added

```
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
```

before the cudnn flag. The rest you might be useful to review

```
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.0 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
```

Hope it helps ;)